# How to get how many hours has users spent playing my game? Steamworks API

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, steamworks-api

How to get how many hours has users spent playing my game? Using Steamworks API and C# in Unity. I have went through a documentation but haven't found anything like that, and thinking that I am missing something.

I should've just went with a simple script that logs minutes played in its own game, but it's too late for that. If anyone can give me a hit or point me a right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an actual answer, but I am pretty sure it is possible because Rocksmith 2014 has achievements that trigger based on 10, 100, 200, etc. hours. I imagine they are polling that information, but I guess it is possible they logged it themselves.

Comment: @TyCobb, yeah, it's either possible or they have done it themselves.

Comment: You should ask these sort of questions over at gamedev.net

Comment: @MickyD, never heard of that place. But thanks!

Comment: There's also https://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: You don't need the Steamworks API to do this. Are you open to solutions without Steamworks API?

Comment: Wut. Just log number of hours played (don't rely on system clock differential) and trigger achievement unlock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might still have a chance to get it to work. As far as I know, there's a way to get the total hours played (as shown in the `Gameplay stats`) by using the deprecated [Community XML Data](https://partner.steamgames.com/documentation/community_data):

> **Player Game Stats**
>
> To retrieve game stats, you will need the game's
>   Steam Community name. Developers can contact Valve to obtain the
>   community name for their game.
>
> You can retrieve stats and achievements for a player per game using
>   the player's 64-bit Steam ID with: Format:
>   http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/[SteamID]/stats/[CommunityGameName]/?xml=1
>
> Example:
>   http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197968575517/stats/L4D/?xml=1

In the example you can see the `hoursPlayed` field on the bottom of the image:

[image: hoursPlayed field]

Now, the problem obviously is that this is deprecated and Steam advices you to *use the web APIs whenever possible*. However, I haven't seen a way to access this data through the web API so I think that this is your best bet without rolling out a custom way of tracking playtime.

Comment: Hmm, that does look interesting and might take quiet some time. Thanks for the info! I'll wait for a few other replies to see what other people have to say; And if nothing, this will be a chosen answer!

Comment: @berdyev It seems really weird to me that this stat wouldn't be available from the web API so hopefully someone turns up with a better answer!

Comment: Do we have any new update on this? I too want to be able to get hours played from a user on every game

Comment: I'm also wondering if there is any new update on this. Can this functionality be accomplished through the Web API or some other method now?